# ActiveMQ-cpp Broker URI with PrefetchPolicy has no effect

Tags: c++, activemq-classic, prefetch, activemq-cpp

I am using activemq-cpp 3.7.0 with VS 2010 to build a client, the server is ActiveMQ 5.8. I have created a message consumer using code similar to the following, based on the CMS configurations mentioned [here](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html). `ConnClass` is a `ExceptionListener` and a `MessageListener`. I only want to consume a single message before calling `cms::Session::commit()`.

```
void ConnClass::setup()
{

    // Create a ConnectionFactory
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactory(
        ConnectionFactory::createCMSConnectionFactory(
            "tcp://localhost:61616?cms.PrefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1");

    // Create a Connection
    m_connection = std::tr1::shared_ptr<cms::Connection>(
        connectionFactory->createConnection());

    m_connection->start();
    m_connection->setExceptionListener(this);

    // Create a Session
    m_session = std::tr1::shared_ptr<cms::Session>(
        m_connection->createSession(Session::SESSION_TRANSACTED));


    // Create the destination (Queue)
    m_destination = std::tr1::shared_ptr<cms::Destination>(
        m_session->createQueue("myqueue?consumer.prefetchSize=1"));

    // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Queue
    m_consumer = std::tr1::shared_ptr<cms::MessageConsumer>(
        m_session->createConsumer( m_destination.get() ));

    m_consumer->setMessageListener( this );

}

void ConnClass::onMessage( const Message* message )
{
    // read message code ...
    // schedule a processing event for
    // another thread that calls m_session->commit() when done
}
```

The problem is I am receiving multiple messages instead of one message before calling `m_session->commit()` -- I know this because the `commit()` call is triggered by user input. How can I ensure `onMessage()` is only called once before each call to `commit()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work that way.  When using async consumers the messages are delivered as fast as the onMessage method completes.  If you want to consume one and only one message then use a sync receive call.

For an async consumer the prefetch allows the broker to buffer up work on the client instead of firing one at a time so you can generally get better proformance, in your case as the async onMessage call completes an ack is sent back to the broker an the next message is sent to the client.

Comment: But why can't the number of messages be controlled by the prefetch "size" options? Or have I understood the prefetch options wrongly?

Comment: You aren't understanding the option.  Its simply an indication to the broker of how much work to try and keep stacked up on the client end.  The word async in async consumer should be your clue.

Comment: I used async so that I do not need to manage an extra thread which I will have to explicitly do so with sync. I am trying to limit the number of messages I receive before I commit the transaction. Are you saying that this cannot be done using the size parameter in the prefetch policy for the async method? Does it mean I should force onMessage to block at the end of the method until I commit if I only want a single message? By the way, I am using SESSION_TRANSACTED mode so I use commit instead of ACKing the messages.

Comment: I'm not sure how many more ways to say prefetch is not a limit.  Its async so you can invent some way to block it or you can just use a sync consumer and make you life much simpler.

Comment: I see, the prefetch size must be an internal library buffer setting then. Thank you for being patient. I will try a sync consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I find this too. However, when I use the Destination URI option ( "consumer.prefetchSize=15" , http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html#Configuring-DestinationURIParameters ) for the asynchronous consumer, It works well.

BTW, I just use the latest ActiveMQ-CPP v3.9.4 by Tim , and ActiveMQ v5.12.1 on CentOS 7.

Thanks!